# List number of queries executed by app

Tags: webforms, sql-server-2012

I have a WebForms app running locally. Is there any tool which will help me to find all queries executed in a request? I cannot see such thing in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is what you are after.

Not sure which edition of SQL you have installed (Express, Dev, etc), if you have SQL Express donwload "advanced tools" to get SQL Profiler.